# Type mismatch: expected :: [String, HNil] => op_rabbit.Handler, actual: String => op_rabbit.Handler

Tags: json, scala, rabbitmq, spray-json

I took the following code from [here](https://github.com/ticofab/Scala-RabbitMQ-Example/blob/master/src/main/scala/io/ticofab/scalarabbitmqexample/actor/QueueListener.scala) in order to consume messages from RabbitMQ. Once a new message is consumed, I want to execute `val init = new Initiator()` in order to run some calculations on this message. 
In the original code the messages are parsed as follows:

```
package io.ticofab.scalarabbitmqexample.model

import play.api.libs.json.Json

/**
  * This is the kind of object that our listener expects in Json format from the queue. So like
  * {
  * "name" : "xxxx",
  * "version" : 1234
  * }
  *
  * @param name An arbitrary String
  * @param version An arbitrary Int
  */
case class MyObject(name: String, version: Int)

object MyObject {
  implicit def myObjectFormat = Json.format[MyObject]
}
```

In my case the parsing is complicated and I don't want to parse the Json String in `MyObject`. What I want is to run `body(as[String])` instead of `body(as[MyObject]) {` (see the code below). Then I'll do parsing inside `init.run(obj)` using `import spray.json._`.

So, my goal is to convert `obj` into String. But if I do so, I get the following compilation error:

> Type mismatch: expected :: [String, HNil] => op_rabbit.Handler,
>   actual: String => op_rabbit.Handler.

```
package org.test.akka_actors

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, Props}
import com.spingo.op_rabbit.Directives._
import com.spingo.op_rabbit.{RabbitControl, Subscription, SubscriptionRef}
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import org.test.Initiator
import org.test.akka_actors.QueueListener.{Listen, Terminate}
import org.test.query.QueryObject

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object QueueListener {

  case object Listen

  case object Terminate

  def props = Props(new QueueListener)

}

class QueueListener extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  // read info from configuration
  val conf = ConfigFactory.load()
  val QUEUE = conf.getString("op-rabbit.rabbit-queue")

  // instantiate a rabbit mq controller
  val RABBIT_CONTROL = context.actorOf(Props[RabbitControl])

  // references to the queue subscriptions
  var queueSubscription: Option[SubscriptionRef] = None
  override def receive: Receive = {

    case Listen =>
      // initialize a queue subscription
      queueSubscription = Some(
        Subscription.run(RABBIT_CONTROL) {
          channel(qos = 3) {
            consume(queue(QUEUE)) {
              body(as[String]) {
                (obj) =>
                  log.debug(s"received the query $obj")
                  val init = new Initiator()
                  init.run(obj)
                  ack
              }
            }
          }
        }
      )

    case Terminate =>
      // close the subscription
      queueSubscription.foreach(_.close())

  }
}
```